# How to use Unleash Feature server from browser (React project)

Tags: javascript, docker, featuretoggle

I am trying to use unleash feature toggle for my React Project. It is running fine for backend server(java sdk is availble). But I cant make unleash request from browser(I am using React as a front end technology). After go through their git repository I came to know there is unleash proxy concept which allow us to use toggles from browser.
When I try to connect from browser through proxy it is giving CORS problem. Please suggest me how to set CORS header to unleash server which is running in docker container.

Answer (score 1):

To use Unleash in frontend and native applications it is recommended to use the Unleash Proxy together with a proxy SDK
https://docs.getunleash.io/sdks/unleash-proxy

The proxy will make sure you don't expose internal toggle configurations to end users and is extremely scalable.